# How can I append a given key to a PostgreSQL JSONB array?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB store.

```
requests: {
 "0000": ["1111"],
 "1111": ["2222"]
}
```

I can add into the store just fine when I have an initial value with:

```
UPDATE users SET requests = jsonb_insert(requests::jsonb, '{2222}', $$["3333"]$$);
```

However if I need to append to the array, it acts like I'm trying to replace the value and throws:

```
UPDATE users SET requests = jsonb_insert(requests::jsonb, '{0000}', $$["4444"]$$);
ERROR:  cannot replace existing key
HINT:  Try using the function jsonb_set to replace key value.
```

Desired output would be:

```
requests: {
 "0000": ["1111", "4444"],
 "1111": ["2222"]
}
```

Seems I'm missing a simple `array_append` or something but can't manage to figure it out.

Comment: `with t(x) as (values('{"0":["1"],"1":["2"]}'::jsonb)) select x, jsonb_set(x, '{0}', x->'0'||'"3"') from t;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not sure about your structure, but with such:

```
create table users (requests jsonb);
```

You are missing array index in your path:

```
t=# select * from users ;
      requests
--------------------
 {"0000": ["1111"]}
 {"1111": ["2222"]}
(2 rows)

Time: 0.257 ms
t=# UPDATE users SET requests = jsonb_insert(requests::jsonb, '{0000,1}', '"4444"');
UPDATE 2
Time: 7.552 ms
t=# select * from users ;
          requests
----------------------------
 {"0000": ["1111", "4444"]}
 {"1111": ["2222"]}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Ya that works :D! However now I have to do a compound query to retrieve the first result. Ok I will structure my data differently.